# Is there a way to stop a cell from updating its value when a condition is satisfied?

Tags: microsoft-excel, worksheet-function

I imported information about the daily currency exchange rate from an external site to Excel.

I use the exchange rate in some formulas every day. The problem is, when the next day comes, exchange rate changes, all the formulas are altered, and I would like them to be altered only for formulas in a row pertaining to the current date. For yesterday, I'd like to keep yesterday's exchange rate.

Is there a way to stop a formula from updating if a condition is satisfied? The condition in this case would be if date to which the formula pertains is less than TODAY().

Comment: No, that would be a circular reference.  You will need to use vba in a worksheet change event.

Comment: I'm going to say the answer depends on how the imported data is saved in excel. If you only have today's imported data (overwriting/discarding previous data), then no. If you are appending into a table new imported data (keeping previous data), then is is possible to update your formulas to take into consideration dates.

Comment: How did you insert the data to Excel? Are there connections for data in Excel?

Answer (score 0):

Yes, you can achieve this result without VBA or even extreme measures.

Not in the manner you are thinking of, however. I'm sure that manner is just where your thinking has gone and that you are not wedded to any particular step or condition though. So...

One way would be to add, or make use of if you already have, a column for your data which has the date the data was obtained. Once you have that, you can do either of two things, and perhaps more, though I'll focus on the two things.

One is a simple `IF()` formula for using your exchange rate value cell. For instance, it could look like this if your date column were column A, your calculation column were column B, and the daily changing exchange rate in cell $M$1:

```
=IF(A1<TODAY(),B1,IF(A1>TODAY(),"",2000*$M$1))
```

On the date in column A, the working formula would calculate. On succeeding days, it will not. As the date matching today becomes farther and farther down the column, new cells that had nothing showing (`""`) will calculate correctly and then join the other cells above them that do not recalculate as the date moves on.

However, if you EVER enter the cell via, say, `F2-Edit`, and press Enter forcing that cell into recalculating, that cell WILL recalculate and fail, resulting in a "0" which is what Excel results to if a formula cannot be calculated due to a circular reference. If you do so by accident, `UNDO` (`Ctrl-Z`) will put you back in business. If noticed before pressing Enter, just pressing ESC instead will preserve things. Formatting changes will not cause problems.

So, it'd work, likely, with some care. Who wants that? Well, someone without a better way.

The second approach is a better way. It'd be easier to do and administer if one created a table with daily dates in column 1 and the exchange rate for each date in column 2. So it would enlarge each day as one added the new exchange rate. Or might be made with many future dates already populating column 1 and the new exchange rate just needing added daily.

Then one's formula would do a lookup of your choice for today's date (`TODAY()`) in column 1 finding the current exchange rate in column 2.

Easy to graft on, placed upon some helper page hidden somewhere. Then your formulas would not need odd tricks. They could reference their date column date for the lookup and always find the exchange rate for that date, even years later. No concerns about interacting with circularity.

This technique is also handy for Tables. One advantage of Tables is how the formulas populate down as each row is added. However, one weakness of Tables is how the formulas populate down as each row is added....

If you need to change a formula, keeping its old form in current rows but using the new form downward as data rows are added, you have a problem. Tables just do not do that. Change all the formulas you want, but new ones keep coming up with the old formula.

Yes, technically, a change of this kind CAN be made to happen, but all the described methods do not work as described. For instance, supposedly, if one changes four rows in a row, supposedly it will become the new formula. In my experience, I have NEVER EVER seen that work with fewer than six rows changed and often 10-30 rows needing changed before Excel gives up and uses the new formula. All that can be done, but... no, it just doesn't work, in practice. Another way is to change to a range then back to a Table. That creates problems, though they are minor, mostly, but it takes the first row of formulas as the master formula and that's NOT likely to be one with the new formula so...

But many formulas can be written to allow changes in how they work to occur outside the Table. For example, your exchange rate. IN the Table, there's just a reference to some value, perhaps a Named Range, perhaps a chunk of formula. That Named Range or chunk can refer to the data range (or Table) holding the changing exchange rate. So new rates can be used without changing the Table formula using it. No difficulties with having to change a Table formula. Something to remember.

But it also shows how often setting up one's data, especially changing data and data being added to, to anticipate these things can make the various bits easy to make changes to, and to use.